# How to encode string to unique long?

Tags: kotlin

The server sends `alphanumerical` ids for a list of items. At the same time, recycler view getItemId (required for has stable ids)  must return Long. How to encode string to unique long?

Comment: You don't give any context for these IDs, or what a ‘recycler view’ might be.  Are they from particular platform or framework (e.g. Android)?  If so, you might get more knowledgeable answers by adding relevant tag(s) and/or explaining it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you probably can't.  Not unless the IDs are guaranteed to be short.

A Long uses 8 bytes, so it can hold 2⁶⁴ (about 1.8×10¹⁹) different values.  So it could only represent that number of strings.  (A result of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).)

However, if the IDs contain only basic ASCII letters (let's assume upper case) and digits — 36 possibilities — and are 13 characters long, then there are 36¹³ (about 1.7×10²⁰) different strings.  That's an order of magnitude more than 2⁶⁴, so some of them will have to map to the same Long value.

(In fact, each Long would map to about 10 IDs on average — and even more if you include strings with fewer characters, and/or a greater range of characters.)

So unless the range of IDs is limited, you'll have to find another approach.